# 'Adam' object has no attribute '_warned_capturable_if_run_uncaptured'

Tags: pytorch, adam

I got above error when I tried to reload the a object of Class for Deep Q Network with target network along with experience replay and train it again.
While there are few similar errors related with tensorflow but I am using PyTorch in google Colab.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: Do not save the entire object. Save the model or its weights and bias (object.model.state_dict()) along with state_dict of optimizer